# Plotly,de un DataFrame de 10 columnas, solamente me representa la gráfica de 8 de ellas

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, plotly

Dispongo del DataFrame

[image: DataFrame]

Quiero representar en una sola gráfica plotly, la evolución de los valores de esas columnas. Para ello ejecuto este script.

```
# Columna Close del DataFrame aapl
import plotly.express as px
df = (df_final/df_final.iloc[0])
px.line(df ,y=df.columns ,title="Cotizaciones normalizadas al cierre")
```

Me devuelve la siguiente gráfica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver que no representa la gráfica de las dos últimas columnas. ¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado ésta solución:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df_portafolio, y=df_portafolio.columns,
              title="Cotizaciones normalizadas al cierre")

fig.update_layout(width=800, height=600)

# Aumenta los intervalos del eje 'y' a 200
fig.update_yaxes(tick0=0, dtick=200)

fig.show()
```

La primera línea importa la biblioteca plotly.express con el alias px, para utilizar sus funciones de manera más sencilla.

La siguiente línea crea una figura con el método px.line, que dibuja un gráfico de líneas. El método recibe como primer argumento el DataFrame df_portafolio, que contiene los datos que se desean visualizar.

La opción y=df_portafolio.columns indica que cada columna del DataFrame se representará en una línea diferente en el gráfico.

La opción title establece el título de la figura.

La siguiente línea ajusta el tamaño de la figura a 800x600 píxeles mediante el método update_layout.

Finalmente, se muestra la figura con el método show()